# Meaning of an equivalence relation on a partition of partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P_1 = \{ C_1, C_2, \cdots , C_m\}$ and $P_2 = \{D_1, D_2, \cdots , D_n\}$ be partitions of a set $A$. Let
$P_3 = \{ C_i \cap D_j : C_i \cap D_j \neq \emptyset\}$. I am able to show that $P_3$ is a partition of $A$. However, I do not quite understand the relationship between the equivalences of the sets. What I mean is,

> If $\equiv _ 1, \equiv _ 2,$ and $\equiv _3$ denote the equivalences on $P_1, P_2,$ and $P_3$, respectively, how can we describe $\equiv _3$ in terms of $\equiv _1 and \equiv _2$?

Comment: $$a\equiv_1b\wedge a\equiv_2b\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv_3b$$

Comment: $C_i\cap D_j \equiv_3 C_k\cap D_{\ell}$ if and only if ($C_i\equiv_1 C_k$ and $D_j\equiv_2 D_{\ell}$) or $C_i\cap D_j = C_k\cap D_\ell = \emptyset$

Comment: @JMoravitz We would be able to deduce the relationships between the equivalence classes using your comment, right? (For example, since $c \in [c]$).

Answer (score 2):

How exactly does a partition create an equivalence relation? If $P_i$ forms a partition of a set $S$, then $a \sim b \iff a,b$ belong to the same $P_i$, is the equivalence relation corresponding to the partition $P_i$.

So, in our case, we want to see the relation between $\equiv_1,\equiv_2$ and $\equiv_3$.

We know that $a \equiv_1 b$ means that $a,b$ belong to the same $C_i$. $a \equiv_2 b$ means that $a,b$ belong to the same $D_j$. $a \equiv_3 b$ means that $a,b$ belong to the same $C_i \cap D_j$.

If $a,b \in C_i \cap D_j$ then of course $a,b \in C_i$ and $a,b \in D_j$, so it is true that $a \equiv_1 b$ and $a \equiv_2 b$.

However, suppose that $a \equiv_1 b$ and $a \equiv_2 b$. So there exist $C_i$ and $D_j$ with $a,b \in C_i$ and $a,b \in D_j$. Therefore, $a,b \in C_i \cap D_j$.

Consequently, $\equiv_3$ can be thought of as the conjunction of $\equiv_1$ and $\equiv_2$. That is, $a\equiv_3 b$ if and only if $a \equiv_1 b$ and $a \equiv_2 b$.

Suppose that the set had finitely many elements. Then, all these equivalence relations are determined by a graph, which has an adjacency matrix, and vice-versa. It can be seen that the adjacency matrix for the partition created by $C_i \cap D_j$ is the entrywise product of the adjacency matrices for the partitions $C_i$ and $D_j$ respectively. This is an easy way of calculating such an equivalence relation given the two separate equivalence relations.

Comment: What can we say about the equivalence classes? For example, if we have two equivalences on a same set, as you mention, and define a new equivalence that holds only if both hold, how can we describe the equivalence class of the new equivalence relation in terms of the old equivalence classes?

Comment: The equivalence classes are exactly of the form $C_i \cap D_j$, where $C_i $ and $D_j$ are equivalence classes of the individual relations (where the intersection is non-empty). This is what I used above : note that $\equiv_3$ is defined using its equivalence class, which we desire to be $C_i \cap D_j$.

Comment: This kind of construction arises in Group Theory E.g. if $H_1, H_2$ are subgroups of  a group $G,$ let $G/H_i=\{gH_i: g\in G\}$ for $i=1,2.$ We can show that $\{g(H_1\cap H_2): g\in G\} =$ $=\{c\cap d :c\in G/H_1\land d\in G/H_2\}$ \ $\{\phi\}.$ In particular if $G/H_i$ is finite for $ i=1,2$ then $G/(H_1\cap H_2)$ is finite.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Very interesting. Thank you for the addition.

Comment: BTW. I read that Poincare gave an example of a non-Abelian group $G$ with  a sub-group $H$ such that the set  $\{gH:g\in G\}$ of left co-sets is finite but the set $\{Hg:g\in G\} $ of right co-sets is infinite... I dk what this example is.